# How to do dynamic signature and return type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a function behave like getter and setter based on if argument present. The logic is already in the function, but TS can not figure the type out and complains.

```
// if no argument, is a getter, and return `Coord` type
cursor(): Coord

// if present, is a setter, return `this` type
cursor(p: Coord): this
```

```
cursor(p){
  if (arguments.length === 0) return this._cursor
  this._cursor = p
  return this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Your argument type for your method that has the implementation has to be compatible with all overloads. In this case you have account for the argument being optional.

```
cursor(): Coord
cursor(p: Coord): this
cursor(p?: Coord) { // p has to be optional
    if (arguments.length === 0) return this._cursor
    this._cursor = p!; // non-null assertion
    return this
}
```

Note that you also need a non-null assertion on p once you know it is defined.

Comment: You just saved my day! I modified a little bit `if (arguments.length === 0 || p === undefined)`.

Comment: Good to hear. Just be aware that will change how it actually works so depends on if you want to support setting the value as undefined. The non-null assertion is a type only check and has no impact on the runtime code.